# Sending multiple SMSes to a subscriber who has more than one number?

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio, mobileconnect, sms

I'm using an Automation, a Data Extension, a Outbound Message to send SMS to customers.
The data is using Salesforce Contact Id as Subscriber Key, and this data may have more than one record has the same subscriber key with different numbers (multiple entries for a contact).

E.g.

- 1st record: SubscriberKey: abcxyz , MobilePhone: 12345
- 2nd record: SubscriberKey: abcxyz , MobilePhone: 67891

I ran the Automation and only one number received 1 SMS and the remaining one didn't receive it.
I also check Activities tab in MobileConnect Contacts and only one number received 1 SMS also. The Automation didn't return any errors.

Can anyone explain what happened? Like what is wrong with my automation steps, etc.. and how I should approach to solve this issue? Many thanks.

Update: in the 2nd attempt, I created an Attribute Group, link the DE with contact. Then I combined between automation and journey. The journey evaluated all records but now only one number received 2 SMSes while it expected that 2 numbers receive different SMS for each one...

Comment: Eventually this is what I did. I raised a case to SFMC and then they made the changes from their backend, after that I was able to send SMS to the same subscriber with different phone numbers. Take note that: it is executed by a Journey and it only has an effect on the BU which we requested SFMC making the changes, therefore if you wanted to have it on multiple BUs then we have to specify which ones they should do the changes

Comment: Hello @duyduc27, was it a paid feature or did you just request them to activate some Business Rule for that?

Comment: @Niko I just asked SFMC side and they changed something from their backend. It's a basic feature in Journey Builder, normally it will evaluate all records in the DE but only send to the primary number if there are multiple records with same Subscriberkey. You don't need to create an Attribute Group for this use case though.